# Google maps Api V2 slow orientation change

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, orientation-changes

I am using google maps Api V2 in my app but i have a problem when the screen rotates. It hasn't any functional problem but when i rotate the screen the change doesn't seem to be instant as in other apps or google default map. I also use the following code:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
    } else {
        map = mapFragment.getMap();
    }
```

but in orientation changes the screen lags. What am i doing wrong? Should i make my actity not to react in orieantaion changes?

Comment: Screen rotation causes recreation of Activity. Do you have any long lasting operations in your `onCreate` or `onResume` methods?

Comment: No i don't have something very heavy on my code.Is something else which can cause the problem? My only guess is that the map activity which shows the map is being started by a fullscreen surfaceview which is in landscape. Is this possible to cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Do checking against fragment itself in hosting Activity (this one work for me):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);

    // Only create a fragment if it doesn't already exist.
    if (mMapFragment == null) {
        mMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        mMapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, mMapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
```